# C# Dividing XML into parts

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to divide an XML file into parts
I have an XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RegistrationOpenData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.gov">
<Description>Registration data is collected by ABC XYZ</Description>
<InformationURL>http://www.example.com/html/hpd/property-reg-unit.shtml</InformationURL>
<SourceAgency>ABC Department of Housing</SourceAgency>
<SourceSystem>PREMISYS</SourceSystem>
<StartDate>2016-02-29T00:03:06.642772-05:00</StartDate>
<EndDate i:nil="true" />
<Registrations>
<Registration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RegistrationID>1</RegistrationID>
<BuildingID>1A</BuildingID>
<element1>E11</element1>
<element2>E21</element2>
<element3>E31</element3>
<element4>E41</element4>
</Registration>
<Registration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RegistrationID>2</RegistrationID>
<BuildingID>2A</BuildingID>
<element1>E21</element1>
<element2>E22</element2>
<element3>E32</element3>
<element4>E42</element4>
</Registration>
</Registrations>
</RegistrationOpenData>
```

And I am trying to fetch the number of nodes trough this code

```
XmlDocument doc = null;
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\Registrations20160229.xml");
XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Registration");
int totalnode = elemList.Count;
int nodehalf = totalnode / 2;
MessageBox.Show(nodehalf.ToString());
```

But after this I am unable to proceed, This code I have used to calculate number of Registration Nodes and then made them into half, now I don't know how to proceed further to split this file, I have total of 158718 entries (Registration Nodes) inside the file (sometimes even more) and I am trying to break all into parts, maybe 3 to 4 parts.

Comment: Can you tell us what the actual symptom is that you're seeing? Breaking the file into 3 to 4 parts isn't necessary. When you say "it failed because of the size", can you go into a bit more detail about that? What error message did you get?

Comment: I tried to load it into an array and then ran "for loop" to get a part of 30,000 entries but it was unable to load complete file at once and showed Out of Memory Exception

Comment: Please show the code that did not work. You have shown us one block of code, and then told us that a _different_ block of code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it should not load whole xml to memory

```
        using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(@"D:\Registrations20160229.xml" , FileMode.Open))){
                        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Registration")
                counter++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        }
```

Comment: calculating number of nodes is working fine with above code, how can I divide xml into parts?

Comment: So if you want get Registration node inside if put this: XElement el = (XElement) XNode.ReadFrom(reader)

Comment: ~Hanumendra the problem here is that you've decided that dividing the XML into parts to make it smaller is the way forward for you. It probably isn't. Please update your question to include the code you've written, the error it is giving, *and your ultimate aim*. It seems like we might have an XY problem (see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ).